# What is the real purpose of magic method __set_state in PHP?

Tags: php, magic-methods

I'm learning about magic methods, reading every site, taking every example, but nothing makes sense to me. Examples like this:

```
class A
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;

    public static function __set_state($an_array) // As of PHP 5.1.0
    {
        $obj = new A;
        $obj->var1 = $an_array['var1'];
        $obj->var2 = $an_array['var2'];
        return $obj;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->var1 = 5;
$a->var2 = 'foo';

eval('$b = ' . var_export($a, true) . ';'); // $b = A::__set_state(array(
                                            //    'var1' => 5,
                                            //    'var2' => 'foo',
                                            // ));
var_dump($b);
```

What is the real purpose? Is for debugging or something?

Comment: It is not a magic quote it is a magic method.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__set_state` is called in response to an instance of your object being passed to the `var_export` function.

`var_export` Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable.

`var_export` takes an optional second parameter – a boolean that determines whether after the variable passed as the first argument is returned as a string instead of output.

An example:

```
class Dummy {
  private $value1_;
  private $value2_;

  function __construct() {
    $this->value1_ = 100;
    $this->value2_ = "100";
  }

  static function __set_state(array $array) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
      echo("$k ==> $v <br/>");
    }
  }
}
$aDummy = new Dummy();
//var_export by it self will output Dummy::__set_state(array( 'value1_' => 100, 'value2_' => '100', ))
var_export($aDummy);
eval(var_export($aDummy, true) . ';');
```

Now the output is this:

> value1_ ==> 100
>
> value2_ ==> 100

`var_export` can produce executable PHP code for the Dummy type with a `__set_state` method defined.

`var_export` takes one argument, and it must be an array. It will contain key-value pairs of the properties or fields of the instance on which it is called.

You can put anything you want in the `__set_state` method.

Comment: As you wrote, "var_export can produce executable PHP code", but your example code clearly breaks this rule, making the function completely worthless.

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy How is that? It clearly turns it into valid PHP code and then runs it in [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Comment: "Parseable" means you can actually copy/paste it into a PHP script and run it. Your output gives a parse error. It should look like this: `array( 'value1_' => 100, 'value2_' => 200 )`

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy I tested it and it workes fine [Check Here](https://eval.in/868850)

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy You might be getting parse error, because `var_export` doesn't put `;` in the end. you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy No, because that is the output of `eval` not `var_export`. Read the code carefully. There is a comment in the code, that displays the output of `var_export`

Comment: Big reveal, now that you accepted my edit with changing the `==>` signs to `=>`, eval finally returns NULL as expected. To match with the final code, you need to change the output exanple too. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155398/discussion-between-mega6382-and-gergely-lukacsy).

Answer (score 18):

`__set_state` can be understood in relation with `var_export`

If you read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php):

> var_export() gets structured information about the given variable. It
> is similar to var_dump() with one exception: the returned
> representation is valid PHP code.

Compare the two:

1. `var_dump($a)`

   `object(A)#1 (2) { ["var1"]=> int(5) ["var2"]=> string(3) "foo" }`
2. `var_export($a)`

   `A::__set_state(array( 'var1' => 5, 'var2' => 'foo', ))`
3. (bonus) `serialize($a)`

   `O:1:"A":2:{s:4:"var1";i:5;s:4:"var2";s:3:"foo";}`

So the second is a valid PHP code, you can run it and end up with similar object.

So what would happen if you removed `__set_state` method? Let's try:

```
class A
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;  
}

$a = new A;
$a->var1 = 5;
$a->var2 = 'foo';

var_export($a); 
// A::__set_state(array( 'var1' => 5, 'var2' => 'foo', ))
```

Still works, right? Let's call it then

```
class A
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;  
}

$a = A::__set_state(array( 'var1' => 5, 'var2' => 'foo', )) 
// Exception: Call to undefined method A::__set_state()
```

Let's bring it back and see:

```
class A
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;

    public static function __set_state($an_array) // As of PHP 5.1.0
    {
        $obj = new A;
        $obj->var1 = $an_array['var1'];
        $obj->var2 = $an_array['var2'];
        return $obj;
    }    
}

$a = A::__set_state(array( 'var1' => 5, 'var2' => 'foo', ));
var_dump($a); 
// object(A)#1 (2) { ["var1"]=> int(5) ["var2"]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

So the real purpose of `__set_state` method is to initialize an object in case someone "serialized" it with `var_export`.

Why someone would need that? Objects serialized with `serialize` need to be unserialized with `unserialize`. But objects saved in files by `var_export` could just be included because it's just a valid PHP code.

Edit:

I would not really call this method `magic` (even though it's in the docs described as such) as there's nothing magical about it. PHP just assumes it's there when `var_export` is called, and it must be there if you want to use whatever `var_export` produced. I would say it's just a convention that it's called `__set_state` - no magic there. But it's just my humble opinion.