# __set_state() - An explanation of the note on the php.net

Tags: php, magic-methods, setstate

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state

> Note: When exporting an object, var_export() does not check whether __set_state() is implemented by the object's class, so re-importing such objects will fail, if __set_state() is not implemented. Particularly, this affects some internal classes. It is the responsibility of the programmer to verify that only objects will be re-imported, whose class implements __set_state().

1) __set_state() is something that we implement ourselves in every object where we want to have it in place?

2) an object can have it or not?

3) what does the "re-importing" mean? var_export does the export so we import or actually "re-import", I dont understand this part.

4) "this particularly affects some internal classes"; more info on this would be good

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441958/what-is-the-real-purpose-of-magic-method-set-state-in-php/46442317#46442317

Answer (score 0):

> 1) __set_state() is something that we implement ourselves in every
>   object where we want to have it in place?

Yes.

> 2) an object can have it or not?

Yes.

> 3) what does the "re-importing" mean? var_export does the export so we import or actually "re-import", I dont understand this part.

```
$c = new C();
$exported_value = var_export($c) # export
$new_c = eval($exported_value) # re-import
```

Also if you stored `$exported_value` as a file, and required it - it would constitute a re-import.

> 4) "this particularly affects some internal classes"; more info on this would be good

Based on [PHP terminology](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.internal.php) I guess it means PHP built in classes, e.g. [Date and Time related classes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php). This basically means that you can't assume that PHP's build in classes implement `__set_state()` method.